# Is there any free/opensource vbscript compiler?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need to compile a wmi vbscript to executable (to automate configuration in several computers). Any free vbscript compiler or any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't you simply run the VBScript at the target machine? What do you need an .exe for?

Comment: Agreed. Knowing the reason why you need an exe will help provide the best possible answer.

Comment: I don't know about where he works, but in the company I work for its easier to distribute an .exe than a .vbs - and it keeps the curious from jacking with the source.

Comment: Is it me, or was there another solution that has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.xneat.com/application-builder/index.htm

looks trusted

Comment: At present time (11/19/2019) this page isn't working. A quick search on internet reveals that there is no home site for this application but appears to be downloadable from third party download places

Answer (score 5):

One thing I would be especially concerned about in doing this is you must really trust the product that is compiling the script. After all, what better way to embed a virus or worm than to offer a free compiler that compiles your VBScript into an unreadable executable.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the best known opensource client side vbscript is baleas2.

If you are talking about server side vb like scripting, then the option list is very big as follows: instant-asp (ib4j-tomcat, java), rbsp (realbasic-server-pages), pbsp (purebasic-server-pages), run-basic (libertybasicscript), and so on with almost all the completely developed commercial alternatives to vb.

Regarding other windows based opensource basic variant in the area of basicwebscripting currently are maven-sb4j, scriptbasic and gbs3 (gambas server pages). Then freebasic server pages may soon be yet another option in the future (after development for curl and proxyserver / fastcgi support).

You may also try using maven-sb4j for jbasic, jabaco, scriptbasic-japi and yabasic-japi.

Answer (score 0):

ok that's interesting i guess, and I fully understand your point!

you can use the WSH Encoder [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E7877F67-C447-4873-B1B0-21F0626A6329&displaylang=en) (Windows Script Host), it's for free you can encrypt your scripts and this way no one can read them (just the not curious ones!)

and if you are looking for some strong and hard work also encryption you can try this book [here](http://sites.google.com/site/martanifayssal/pro-decrypting-vbscript-viruses)

Comment: Be careful with you syntax...  The WSH Encoder is encoding the script and not encrypting it.  There is a unencoder that can turn it all back if you need to...

Answer (score 0):

Try vbs to exe. It's command line but works fine.
http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=v2e